# HTML and JS button with date validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to add a div when the dates year are wrong and hide it when it's fixed.
I don't know how to do it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
id="searchbtn" onclick = "Scroll()">Search</button>
</div>
```

**JS for Date Validation**

```
if (parseInt(startDate) < parseInt(endDate)) {
        // their dates are OK
        $("#searchbtn").removeAttr("disabled", "");            
    } else {
        // dates are Bad
        $("#searchbtn").attr("disabled", "");
        $('#sortDateFrom').css("border-color", "red");
        $('#sortDateFrom').css("border-width", "4px");
        $('#sortDateTo').css("border-color", "red");
        $('#sortDateTo').css("border-width", "4px");
    }
});
});
```

**JS for Scroll()**

```
function Scroll() {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#results").offset().top},"slow");
}
```

Comment: Why does Scroll comes into this plan?

Comment: Can you create js fiddle ?